# Ember CLI doesn't run jshint or load any tests

Tags: ember-cli

So this used to work all fine, but ever since I updated ember-cli from 0.1.8 to 0.1.12 my tests won’t start and jshint never checks the files I work with on save.

```
ember test
version: 0.1.12
Built project successfully. Stored in “/[...]/tmp/class-tests_dist-h3LlgY3C.tmp".

1..0
tests 0
pass  0
fail  0
```

And on `http://localhost:4200/tests` it looks fine but `0 assertions of 0 passed, 0 failed.`.

I’ve followed the upgrade path, and I don’t think I’ve missed any dependencies on my bower.json or package.json.

Can any one here spot if there’s some dependency that’s all wrong?

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "2.0.0",
    "broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "1.6.1",
    "ember-cli": "0.1.12",
    "ember-cli-6to5": "3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-autoprefixer": "0.2.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.3.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.7",
    "ember-cli-fastclick": "1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-flash": "0.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.5.4",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-pretender": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-responsive": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-sass": "3.0.3",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "0.7.2",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-oauth2": "0.7.2",
    "ember-cli-spinjs": "0.3.0",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.14.1",
    "ember-document-title": "0.1.2",
    "ember-export-application-global": "1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "express": "4.8.5",
    "glob": "4.0.5",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "0.3.0",
    "grunt-svgstore": "0.4.1"
  }
}
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "2.0.0",
    "jquery": "2.1.3",
    "ember": "1.9.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.14.1",
    "ember-resolver": "0.1.11",
    "ember-i18n": "2.9.0",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli/ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.5",
    "qunit": "1.17.1",
    "moment": "2.9.0",
    "cookie-monster": "0.3.0",
    "inuit-functions": "0.2.0",
    "inuit-mixins": "0.2.3",
    "inuit-normalize": "3.0.2",
    "inuit-reset": "0.1.1",
    "inuit-box-sizing": "0.2.0",
    "inuit-shared": "0.1.3",
    "spin.js": "2.0.2",
    "inuit-clearfix": "0.2.1",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker.git#1.3.17",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "3.3.3",
    "matchmedia": "0.2.0",
    "fastclick": "1.0.6",
    "animate-sass": "0.6.2",
    "pretender": "0.6.0",
    "ember-simple-auth": "0.7.2",
    "gmaps": "https://github.com/hpneo/gmaps.git#~0.4.16",
    "jQuery.mmenu": "~4.7.5",
    "susy": "~2.2.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "handlebars": "2.0.0",
    "ember": "1.9.1",
    "moment": "2.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you do your update? Did you follow something like what is detailed [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases) under **Setup** and **Project Update**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did a new update and followed the guides VERY carefully this time and now it works. Thank you @mikeazo for commenting. I can't really say either what i did wrong, but it's working again. So all I can say is FOLLOW THE UPGRADE GUIDES and don't rush through them.